# How do I rewrite URL's based on title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, url-rewriting, url-routing

This is a fairly open-ended question, and I'm just looking for the best possible avenue.

Users can post links with titles. And I want my URL's for SEO purposes to display those titles. Much in the same way I believe stackoverflow works.

So if the title is "My foobar just made out with my cat"

I would like the URL to be : `www.website.com/posts/My-foobar-just-made-out-with-my-cat`

Any ideas?

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this in an old Rails 2.x app.  There may be a better approach to scrubbing the title...

(goes in your model)

```
def to_param
  seo_uri
end

def seo_uri
  "#{self.id}-#{self.title.gsub(/[^a-z0-9]+/i, '-').gsub(/-{2}/, '-').gsub(/-$/, '')}"
end
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

Comments on this answer indicated there is a new method available for Rails 3 users: `#parameterize`.  The [Rails API document for this method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001055) shows how it should be used (cut-n-paste):

```
class Person
  def to_param
    "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
  end
end

@person = Person.find(1)
# => #<Person id: 1, name: "Donald E. Knuth">

<%= link_to(@person.name, person_path %>
# => <a href="/person/1-donald-e-knuth">Donald E. Knuth</a>
```

Comment: That's very clever Brian! How does that rewrite the standard URL'S though?

Comment: doesn't parameterize() do this?

Comment: @Paul - Wasn't aware of that new inflection until you mentioned it!  Thanks for the heads up!  I'm updating my answer to include this for Rails 3 users...

Comment: Wow that's amazing. Amazing answer! I had no idea

Comment: parameterize is available in Rails 2.3.

Comment: Hey Brian had to give the answer to you as I didn't have to include any new gems to make this happen! I'm still curious how the def to_param overrides default_url's

Comment: I believe that 'under the covers' rails uses `ActiveRecord::Base#to_param` to construct your url (standard being the id).  Here, we are over-riding the `to_param` method in our model to return what we want.  Here is a link to the api doc for `#to_param`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-to_param

Answer (score 2):

There's a really awesome plugin, [FriendlyId](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) which will handle all this for you. Loads of really clever features, including scopes and handling of 301 redirects on title change. This differs from stackoverflow and Brian's method in that the id isn't used in the url.