# Stack Overflow-like URL routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

So I want my app to generate routes like stack overflow

```
questions/:id/:title
```

How can I do this in rails?

Comment: :title is the page title generated by the view

Comment: Similar but not exact, I'm sure you can work out the logic to get your desired result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413789/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-based-on-title/4413833#4413833

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html

hope this can help others!

Answer (score 3):

Please note that:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434266/stack-overflow-like-url-routes-in-rails-3

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434266/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434266/you-can-put-wathever-you-want-here
```

Are the same. I guess stackoverflow just does that in order to provide some context if you see just the link there.

So, your route would be just this one:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434266/
```

which should be something like:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/:id
```

You can ignore the rest of the url

Comment: I realized this, and wanted to add the same context to url's.

Comment: why do people keep voting for this?  It dosn't even answer my question at all! I KNOW THAT THEY ARE THE SAME THING!

Comment: How does this *not* answer your question? You can throw anything you want at the end of the url.

Comment: please follow the link below that I posted.  this is what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @jtmkrueger they upvote it because this is all you need. Take the name as an extra parameter and drop it if you want to

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the question "How can I generate a URL like questions/:id/:title in Rails?". OP wants to know how to append a question's title to the URL.

Comment: So the user wants to know how to concatenate 2 strings?

Comment: Here, on SO, they basically redirect you to the correct URL if you specify an empty or wrong title. Nothing special: find by id, compare title and redirect if necessary. Just use your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you could ever want to know about routes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Take a look specifically at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments. What you want to do is create a route that maps to the controller and passes the question id and title as paramaters. Then your controller action will grab that information and render the correct view. The title attribute has to be accessible in your controller, it can't be only accessible in your view.

Comment: i've read that.  I can't find anything in there that really addressed my question

Comment: Take a look specifically @ http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments what you want to do is create a route that maps to the controller and passes the question id and title as paramaters. Then your controller action will grab that information and render the correct view. The title attribute has to be accessible in your controller, it can't be only accessible in your view.