# Wrong url with parameterize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting, parameterized

I'm trying to have URL rewriting with parameterize, as explain here : [How do I rewrite URL's based on title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413789/how-do-i-rewrite-urls-based-on-title)

Here is my model :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  self.per_page = 5

  def to_param
    "#{title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

And my link :

```
<%= link_to(article.title, blog_article_path(article), {:class => "blog_title"}) %>
```

THe problem is that I don't have a link like `/blog/article/"my-article-title"` but I have `/blog/article."my-article-title"`, which is wrong and not interpreted.

Do you know the reason ?

My route.rb :

```
get "blog/index"
get "blog/category"
get "blog/article" (I don't use the show action of my article controller, is it the reason ?)

resources :categories

resources :articles
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your `routes.rb` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `link_to` the way you are by passing in a resource only really works when you actually use resources in your route file.

This is the difference (rake routes output) with using a non-resourceful route and one generated by resources:

```
blog_article GET    /blog/article(.:format)

article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)
```

When you use `article_path(@article)` it will fill in `:id` with the id of the resource.

I'd advise you to use the show action of the articles controller so you would have `/blog/articles/:id` or you could do something like this if you really want that routing:

```
get "blog/article/:id" => "articles#show", :as => 'blog_article'
```

which turns into:

```
blog_article GET    /blog/article/:id(.:format)
```

The [official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes) have some good info on this.

Comment: That's because find will always search the record by it's ID column. In essence it just does `"my-article-title".to_i` which evaluates to 0 in this case. There are 2 options, use "#{id}-title.parameterize" so it generates urls like /articles/1-my-title (when doing .to_i it will find record id 1), or by using another column to find the article. I suggest looking at this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised